# MIT App Inventor 2: May I / How to place alarms in the Android notification area?

Tags: android, app-inventor

With `MIT Inventor 2`,
may I create a `Notification Area Notification` caused by an Alarm, which is placed in the notification area of an Android smartphone?
So that I may create a `silent alarm`, as standard with Android apps?
And if so, how to do it?

See `Requirement #5` [in this document](http://github.com/aporter/coursera-android-labs/blob/master/DailySelfie/Lab8b-DailySelfie/Lab-DailySelfie.pdf) ( describing an Android programmming task, which is not intended to be implemented with a code generator, of course )
My research:

1. With the discontinued `MIT Inventor 1`, it was obviously possible to create notifications, which can be viewed by pulling down the status bar. See "AlertMe: Texting in the background, when app is not running".
   http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/alertme.html
   I didn´t find a corresponding tutorial for `MIT Inventor 2`...
2. With `MIT Inventor 2`, you may create Notifications, 
   which are displayed immediately by modale windows, 
   or which are pushed to Android logfiles, invisible to ordinary Android smartphone users. 
   I didn´t find any option to create a "silent alarm" visible just in the notification area. Am I right?!

So is this maybe a "lost feature" of version1, not available with version2, so one of the very-raw drawbacks?

As there are now frameworks based on `MIT Inventor` like `Punya` and `Ai2LiveComplete`, does any of it cover this "silent messaging"?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/5QYEFW_olGM/oOeCCgb6AQAJ). The Punya framework offers Google Cloud Messaging, see also the [overview about the different App Inventor distributions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ai4a/ajG4Q6UrRR8).

Comment: Thanks for the comparison of App Inventor distributions, but for me there is still the question, may I call an alarm by clock ( every x seconds, minutes, hours..) which creates a notification, just available if the user visits the notification area?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there the following alternatives:

1. The `Texting` component can display a notification also in App Inventor 2, see also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html#Texting). This feature however is available only in the United States.
2. The [Punya Framework](http://punya.mit.edu/getting-started) offers a Google Cloud Messaging component, see also [here](http://air.csail.mit.edu/punya/tutorials/#push). See also the [Overview: Different App Inventor distributions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ai4a/ajG4Q6UrRR8).

   If you use another server, you always have to think about
   a) is it a reliable service?
   b) will it be updated (bug fixes and new features)?
   because once you create a project using another server, which uses other blocks, you will not be able to import your project back into MIT App Inventor anymore!
3. I also can offer a simple [Notification Extension](https://puravidaapps.com/notification.php) to send a notification. As you know, App Inventor apps have some restrictions. Which means for the Notification extension: the app must be still running (at least in the background) to be able to send a notification after n seconds.

   The App Inventor Extensions are currently in testing. See the
   [announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ) for more information about how to use an App
   Inventor Extension.
    [image]